# Parse Args with R.E

Tags: regex, sh

can you help me?

I want parse this: {'$', '$0', '$qwerty', '$123'} # $Previous_Character_Or_Group_Repeated_0_Or_More_Time

In ScriptShell:

```
echo "$" | grep '^\$.*$' 
$
```

it's work.

```
echo "$1" | grep '^\$.*$'
echo "$hello" | grep '^\$.*$'
echo "$Qwerty123" | grep '^\$.*$'
```

it's doesn't work.

thx for reply,

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Just use single quote, not double quote like this:

```
echo '$1' | grep '^\$.*$'
$1
```